# JavaScript: send notification to admin for scam messages

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a chat system implemented on my site. I want the user not to send any off-topic message to others that offend others.

I am saving messages through ajax but unable to put any restrictions on the message.

```js
$('#insert-message-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  message = $('#message').val();
  if (message == "") {
  } else {
    file = $('#file').val();
    if (file == "") {
      message_file = file;
    } else {
      message_file = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
    }
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "insert_inbox_message.php",
      data: {
        single_message_id: single_message_id,
        message: message,
        file: message_file
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#message').val('');
        $('#file').val('');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? `if (message == "" || message.indexOf("$hit") !=-1)  {` ???

Comment: You must to have an index with all your messages and validate against the inputted data, isn't?

Comment: It would be much cleaner if you split up your functionality. Instead of having the restrictions/validations directly into the AJAX function, make it a separate function instead. Then upon triggereing the action of submitting, then you can do `if( validation() ){ /* AJAX function here */ }` this will make your code much cleaner, since you have now separated the two functionalities. Then you are also able to do other functionalities, such as throwing error messages or logging certain stuff etc. depending on your validation.

Comment: I think the best thing is to put the message validation functions on backend... not on fronted